# I can't get of this error and end up in tty mode after I start my system

Tags: boot, package-management, grep, tty, passwd

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/passwd.postinst: 21: grep: not found
groupadd: group 'shadow' already exists
Group ID 42 has been allocated for the shadow group.  You have either
used 42 yourself or created a shadow group with a different ID.
Please correct this problem and reconfigure with dpkg --configure passwd''.
Note that both user and group IDs in the range 0-99 are globally
allocated by the Debian project and must be the same on every Debian
system.
dpkg: error processing package passwd (--configure):
 installed passwd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 passwd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What is the output of `type -a grep`?

Comment: bash: type: grep: not found

Comment: Run `sudo apt install grep`.

Comment: Please correct this problem and reconfigure with dpkg --configure passwd''.

Note that both user and group IDs in the range 0-99 are globally
allocated by the Debian project and must be the same on every Debian
system.
dpkg: error processing package passwd (--configure):
 installed passwd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 passwd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: whenever i start my system i have to pass through recovery mode so i dont stuck in tty

Comment: after that whenever i try install anything it give such error that i posted.

Comment: What is the output of `getent group | grep 42`?